# On Linux, does /dev/random unblocking imply that /dev/urandom is seeded?

Tags: implementation, randomness

Linux has the familiar problem that /dev/random blocks too much (insisting on being information-theoretically secure), while /dev/urandom doesn't block enough (it will return data before it's been adequately seeded). The new `getrandom()` system call does the Right Thing, but as of this writing it's not yet universally available in the major distros.

My question is: if I succeed at reading a single byte from /dev/random, does this imply that /dev/urandom is seeded? I've spent some time staring at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c but haven't been able to figure this out. Entropy provided by device drivers gets mixed into the input pool, then the input pool feeds separate `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` output pools, but I can't glean the conditions which trigger transfers from the input pool to the output pools, or (consequently) whether it's possible for /dev/random to be fed while /dev/urandom starves.

Comment: Take a look specially to the second link on this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117496/how-long-to-re-seed-dev-urandom-in-a-virtual-machine/118144#118144. It addresses your question and some extra related points that could be useful.

Comment: @SergioAndrésFigueroaSantos What part of that article do you believe addresses my question? The closest it seems to come is that part that says you can work around /dev/urandom's bad behavior by saving a seed at shutdown and writing it back at boot time.

Comment: All of it, but around the middle of the page  there is a drawing representing the fact that the only difference between the two sources is that _/dev/random_ blocks.

Comment: @SergioAndrésFigueroaSantos that diagram, although I suppose it would imply an affirmative answer to my question,  is inaccurate. If you refer to the kernel code I linked in my question,  you'll see that there are in fact *three* entropy pools, not just one as the diagram depicts. One is for /dev/random, one is for /dev/urandom,  and one feeds the other two. Yes,  they all use the same mixing and extraction algorithms,  but they may be fed at different times. My question concerns the details of this timing.

Comment: I believe the main point to take from the link is that it doesn't really matter. "Even disregarding issues like availability and subsequent manipulation by users, the issue of entropy “running low” is a straw man. About 256 bits of entropy are enough to get computationally secure numbers for a long, long time". But even if it did, why start with the source code and not with the design? Wouldn't the insights you get from the source code be limited to that specific distro?

Comment: @SergioAndrésFigueroaSantos yes,  once a sufficient amount of entropy has been added to the /dev/urandom pool, it's good indefinitely until the next reboot. Its longstanding flaw,  which is one of the things `getrandom()` was written to address, is that it will return data even before that, which is a hazard for any code that might run early in the boot process. For code that has this concern, the cleanest solution is to use `getrandom()`, but I'm investigating the soundness of "select() on /dev/random before reading from /dev/urandom" as an alternative approach for older systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally untangled what this code is doing.

**YES**.

The quick version of why this is true is that the first 128 bits of entropy which the system collects get mixed directly into the nonblocking pool, bypassing the input pool. The logic which implements this is part of each of the `add_foo_randomness()` functions:

```
 r = nonblocking_pool.initialized ? &input_pool : &nonblocking_pool;
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=4.5#L804
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=4.5#L924

And per http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=4.5#L677, `nonblocking_pool.initialized` is set when its `entropy_total` exceeds 128 bits. So by the time anything is available from /dev/random, /dev/urandom has been seeded.

For completeness, here's the rest of the story on how the entropy pools are managed:

- All pools, even the nonblocking pool, have entropy estimates that are credited when new entropy is mixed in and debited when entropy is extracted.
- As detailed above, the first 128 bits of entropy collected get written and credited to the nonblocking pool; everything thereafter gets written and credited to the input pool.
- If the input pool is overflowing (i.e. its entropy estimate is approaching its total size), then this triggers a transfer from the input pool to either the blocking or the nonblocking pool, on an alternating basis. Pools skip their turn if they're already at least 75% full. (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=4.5#L692)
- Reading from /dev/random always triggers a transfer from the input pool to the blocking pool (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=4.5#L1177). Reading from /dev/urandom triggers a transfer from the input pool to the nonblocking pool only if there has been no such transfer in the past 60 seconds (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=4.5#L983).
- The amount transferred is (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/random.c?v=4.5#L995):

  - Typically equal to the amount being read from /dev/{u}random
  - But at least 64 bits
  - But not more than the current entropy estimate for the input pool
  - And not more than that estimate minus 128 bits if the transfer is to the nonblocking pool. (EDIT: I think this is a bug. See http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=145945873501946&w=2)